# Unable to save the TF-IDF vectorizer

Tags: python, machine-learning, pickle, tf-idf, joblib

I'm workig on multi-label classification problem. I'm facing issue while saving the TF-IDf verctorizer and as well as model using both pickle and joblib packages.

Below is the code:

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=0.00009, max_features=200000, smooth_idf=True, norm="l2", \
                         tokenizer = lambda x: x.split(), sublinear_tf=False, ngram_range=(1,3))
x_train_multilabel = vectorizer.fit_transform(x_train)
x_test_multilabel = vectorizer.transform(x_test)

classifier = OneVsRestClassifier(SGDClassifier(loss='log', alpha=0.00001, penalty='l1'), n_jobs=-1)
classifier.fit(x_train_multilabel, y_train)
predictions = classifier.predict(x_test_multilabel)
```

Error Message while saving the TF-IDF vectozier.

[image]
[image]

Any suggestions ?
Thanks in advance.